# How to use user input information for new post to server (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs

How to modify so that we can use user input via empty fields on app rather than the current info...?

```
var dataObj = {

ID: "INFO226", 

Name: "Application Development",  

Overview: "An introduction to the use of software languages and tools for rapid application...",

Year: 2018,

Trimester: "1", 

LectureTimes: "Thursday 12.40pm", 

LecturerID: "1",
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question is not carrying the controller /html code snippet, so its really hard for me to understand what exactly you need here.
As per my assumption I am concluding your requirement and here is my answer to you..

Instead of var dataObj, use **$scope.dataObj** in **controller**.

In HTML,

```
<input type="text" ng-model="dataObj.ID" id="dataObjId"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="dataObj.Name" id="dataObjName"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="dataObj.Overview" id="dataObjOverview"/>
<input type="text" ng-model="dataObj.Year" id="dataObjYear"/>
```

and so on.

On submit of the form or on click of the Save button or so on your page, the dataObj scope is now modified with the user's input and can be submitted without pushing the data further.